# how to get all child view direct and hirechery in android

Tags: android

I have an UI like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
       <TextView />
       <RelativeLayout>
             <TextView />
             <TextView />
             <LinearLayout>
                  <TextView />
             </LinearLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to access all TextViews programmatically and change some attributes but 
I don't want use id and findViewById, because I have a multi layout which I want to perform the same changes in them, i.e.: change the fonts of TextViews.

How can I access all the TextViews whether direct or hierarchy of a view, like RelativeLayout in a loop or in a list?

Comment: It would be trivial to write a recursive (or even a linear) algorithm to walk over the view hierarchy. Most of the solution is already outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668897/android-get-all-children-elements-of-a-viewgroup/). All you'll need to do is add some type checking for the particular view type you're interested in.

Answer (score -1):

```
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout);

    for(i = 0; i <= mLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){ 
        View view = mLinearLayout.getChildAt(i); 
        if (view instanceof TextView){ 
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            // TODO do your stuff 
        } 
    }
```

if you have ViewGroups in your RelativeLayout then you need to write a recursive method.

Comment: *"If you have ViewGroups in your RelativeLayout (...)"* - based on the question, there's not much of an *if* here... There is a `RelativeLayout` in the first level, and a `LinearLayout` in the second.

Comment: He should research some to improve himself :P